# Algorithm to print all possible of an array if each element can be incremented or decremented by a value k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, sorting, data-structures

For better understanding of minimize height of array problem (https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimize-the-heights3351/1), I wanted to first solve it via Brute Force approach where each element of the array can be be incremented as well as decremented by once, so there will be total 2 to the power n, (n = length of array) possible combination of arrays & then find the minimal difference, but that wouldn't be an optimal solution. Still if I want to do it, how would I get those combinations?

For example:

```
If array = {2,5,9} & k = 2

Combinations are:
 2-2, 5-2, 9-2
 2+2, 5+2, 9+2

 2-2, 5+2, 9+2
 2-2, 5+2, 9-2
 2-2, 5-2, 9+2

 2+2, 5-2, 9-2
 2+2, 5+2, 9-2
 2+2, 5-2, 9+2
```

I tried the contiguous array approach, but its not working:

```
int arr[] = {4,5,6};
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("");

        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("");


            for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
                if (k == j) {
                    System.out.print(arr[k] + "  +2 " + "  , ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(arr[k] + "  -2 " + "  , ");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can think of creating these arrays recursively

```
fn(int a[],int index,finalArray[][](array of arrays)){
  if(index == a.length()){
   finalArray.push(a);
   return;
  }
  a[index]+=2;
  fn(a,index+1,finalArray)
  a[index]-=4;
  fn(a,index+1,finalArray)
  a[index]+=2
}
```

you can also check it here :https://ideone.com/Y2L5DQ

Comment: you gave a nice approach to the problem but actually its not working...for example for array {3,1, 9} I am getting one of the combinations as {5, -1, 9} which is not acceptable as either addition or subtraction is mandatory on each element

Comment: You need a final `a[index]+=2;` as the last line of the function, to return the current value to its starting point, else you get "drift" in the values.

Comment: @RaffleBuffle Thanks a lot dear. After a bit of digging I found that the problem is a variation of power set problem, but what i still fail to understand I how to found out that there is a "drift" and how did you think in that direction, because for me it was really difficult to dry run this recursion..

Answer (score 1):

It was given that the problem can be solved using greedy method. We have to find the  heights of `highest` and `lowest` tower. But since we need to **minimise** the difference between them, we need to find **reduced highest** tower and **increased lowest** tower. These words are key to understand the solution.
Here's the straight forward greedy approach:

1. First of all, define 2 variables to store maximum and minimum height of tower.
2. **Greedy Step**: For each element of array, add and subtract `k`. Now, we need to store maximum and minimum heights. Now while storing maximum and minimum heights, remember that our aim is to **minimise** the difference between the maximum and minimum heights of tower. So we need **reduced maximum height** and **increased minimum height**.
3. Finally after obtaining overall reduced maximum height and increased minimum height,we get minimised difference of maximum height and minimum height.

Program code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        int k,n;
        int arr[101];
        cin>>k>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                cin>>arr[i];
        }
        int minh = INT_MAX,maxh=INT_MIN;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(arr[i] >=k){
                        if(arr[i]-k > maxh){
                                maxh=arr[i]-k;
                        }
                }
                if(arr[i]+k < minh){
                        minh=arr[i]+k;
                }
        }
        cout<<maxh<<endl<<minh<<endl;
        cout<<(maxh-minh)<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```